# FFMPEG - How to keep metadata while transcoding

Tags: command-line, audio, ffmpeg, metadata, aac

Ffmpeg newbie here. I put together a command line that takes anything put into it and outputs audio in aac:

```
for %%a in ("*.*") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -vn -c:a aac -b:a 320k "Output\%%~na.aac" 
pause
```

But when I use that to transcode a music file into aac that has metadata in it, it doesn't get carried over into the output file. Is there a way/modification to that command line that would copy the metadata?

Comment: Change `.aac` to `.m4a`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt you can dump metadata into raw ADTS AAC. Change `.aac` to `.m4a` and the metadata should be preserved.